# Trailing route polyline on marker move event

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using `leaflet` and `pubnub` libraries to move marker smoothly on Google maps, with real-time data. This functionality is working fine and marker moves smoothly on map from one point to next point.

But I could not find a way to draw a route polyline from marker to destination and trailing line with marker `move` event. I want to show route line same as *Uber*, from car icon to destination and trailing line with car movement.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using the following `pubnub` SDK:
https://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/map/bus/

Here is my `pubnub` object initialization code:

```
var connectline = 0;
var lastlng = [40.80523269999999, -73.7412536];
var pubnub = new PubNub({
    publishKey: 'pub-c-5e4c8233-c59b-448c-a809-9c09f61715XX',
    subscribeKey: 'sub-c-74a7e51a-ad14-11e4-a808-02ee2ddab7XX'
});

var trip = '134386886'; // '134386875';
var channel = 'TRIP_' + trip;

alert("channel name=" + channel);

var map = eon.map({
    pubnub: pubnub,
    id: 'map',
    options: {
        center: new L.LatLng(40.80523269999999, -73.7412536),
        zoom: 15
    },
    mbId: 'ianjennings.l896mh2e',
    mbToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaWFuamVubmluZ3MiLCJhIjoiZExwb0p5WSJ9.XLi48h-NOyJOCJuu1-h-Jg',
    channels:[channel],
    message: function (data) {
        map.setView(data[trip].latlng, 15);

    },
    transform: function(m) {
        var a = {};
        a[m.common.trip_id] = {
            latlng: [m.common.latitude, m.common.longitude],
            data: m.common
        }
        return a;
    },
    rotate: true,
    // history: true,
    marker: function (latlng, data) {
        var icon = new Icon();
        var parisKievLL = [lastlng, latlng];
        var marker = L.Marker.movingMarker(parisKievLL, [10000], {icon:icon}).addTo(map);
        lastlng = latlng;
        // alert('marker data=' + JSON.stringify(data));
        // alert('market latlng' + JSON.stringify(latlng));
        // var latlng = [data.latitude, data.longitude];
        var addressMarker = L.marker([40.80523269999999, -73.7412536]).addTo(map);
        marker.bindPopup('car #:' + data.device_id);
        return marker;
    }
});
```

Comment: The solution is here using Mapbox polyline: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2016-02-19-plotting-iss-real-time-mapbox/

Comment: Craig, LINE increment is working fine in my script but i am having issue in trailing line if marker move towards destination.

Comment: I would suggest submitting your full HTML file to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com). Reference this SO link so that answer can be posted back.